# Anniversary XP bonus boost

Tags: diablo-iii

How does the 'double experience' or '+100% xp bonus' from the anniversary event work with other boosts such as from higher difficulty levels?

Torment I has a base 300% XP bonus, for the duration of this event will that become 400% bonus ('+100%') or 600% XP rate ('double')?

Comment: [Official announcement](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/18388260/100-bonus-gold-find-and-exp-happy-birthday-reaper-of-souls-22-03-2015): _the bonuses provided will stack multiplicatively with existing in-game bonuses, including those provided by items, Shrines, Pools of Reflection, and Paragon points._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's multiplicative not additive. The bonus is doubled. So for your example it becomes 600%

[source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/18388260/100-bonus-gold-find-and-exp-happy-birthday-reaper-of-souls-3-22-2015)